# AngularJS ng-class remove class

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have the following code that is causing me meaningless pain

```
<input type="text" ng-class="GLOBAL_ERROR == 1 ? 'error-branch' : 'defaulttxt'" ng-model="frm.FirstName" name="FN" ng-required="true" ng-minlength="2" ng-maxlength="100"/>
```

When the page is loading the form is invalid so the class is `error-branch` after the data is loaded though the class does not change to `defaulttxt`

How do you fix this? Should i use something like the following?

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){

  });
```

Comment: How do you change GLOBAL_ERROR?

Comment: Why isn't your ng class an object? It should be wrapped in {}, right?

Comment: @dfsq GLOBAL_ERROR changes in the rootscope and i tested it and it works perfectly with the ng-messages but not with the ng-class as shown above

Comment: Would make sense to show relevant code. What you posted is not enough to help you, the code is okay.

Comment: @dfsq i set the `GLOBAL_ERROR = 1` in the `$scope` just to be sure any ideas as to why that might happen?

Comment: You can replicated the issue in plunkr. Otherwise it's hard to guess.

Comment: Oh i got it its because the value of GLOBAL_ERROR remains the same how can i say in the ng-class `GLOBAL_ERROR ==1` and field is `invalid`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks to @dfsq i realized the solution while replicating the issue on plunkr

the solution is to add one more condition to the GLOBAL_ERROR ==1 and it is

`GLOBAL_ERROR==1 && myForm.FN.$invalid`

Case closed damnnn